# If $u=(ab)(cd)$, and $g=(ab)(de)$ are two permutations, what does $u^g$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, notation, permutations

If $u=(ab)(cd)$, and $g=(ab)(de)$ are two permutations, what does $u^g$ mean? So that $uu^g=(cde)$

Edit: I computed that in fact $uu^g=(cde)\qquad$ and $vv^g=(bec)\qquad$ hold where $v=(abcde)$

So now from this result I must show that any nontrivial normal subgroup of $A_5$ must contain an element of order 3.

Comment: probably means "conjugate by"

Comment: As @zig wrote, so, either $gug^{-1}$ or $g^{-1}ug$, depending on which convention you adopt.

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In group theory, the notation $u^g$ usually means $g^{-1}ug$ so that $u^{gh}=(u^g)^h$.